# Какой способ реализации autocomplete выбрать?

Tags: datalist, autocomplete, jquery-ui, html5

Добрый день, стоит такая задача сделать autocomplete формы поиска на сайте, как это сделано на Яндексе и Гугле. Но брать значения, которые будут предлагаться для поиска мне нужно из БД. Как лучше реализовать эту задачу с помощью html5 тега datalist или с помощью AutoComplete jQuery UI? Если еще варианты решения этой задачи?

P.S. Вариантов для подстановки около 200 млн. слов

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне лучше реализовать autocomplete?

Comment: Неужели никто не знает как правильно решить эту задачу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

думаю что лучше с помощью jQuery UI, это все таки более универсальный вариант. Раз у вас так уж много вариантов, то начинать поиск где то с 3го символа либо сразу выставлять лимиты при поиске, чтоб вам все 200 млн. слов не выбросило. Вообщем нужно конкретнее смотреть на задачу. А на счет примера, далеко ходить ненадо - офф сайт http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote. Смотрите, пишите, тестируйте.